# putting values from array into map

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashmap

I have an array of ints that I want to put into a map.  Each value from the array must be put with another value of the array so that if I have an array of 0, 2, 4, 7 there should be every combination (e.g. [0, 2], [0, 4], [0, 7] but also [2, 0], [4, 0] and [7,0] and same for rest of values).  I'm trying to achieve that by Map and then I try to display it.  However I have some problems with that.  How I should fix that or is there any better way to achieve that?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map;

public class Prac1 {
    public Map<Integer, Integer> count(int[] A){
        int k = A.length;       
        Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++){
                m.put(i, j);
            }
        }       
        return m;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] A = {0, 2, 4, 7};
        Map<Integer,Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++){
                m.put(A[i], A[j]);
            }
        }           

        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(m.get(i));
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: for Map you can have only have unique keys, so no [0,1] & [0,2] last would remain in map

Comment: What is it that you what to achieve ;

Comment: I want to produce a 2 dimensional array int[][] that will scale to the array provided and that will contain values of the underlying array combined with each other.  Then I want to display it.

Comment: was wrong it can't be done that way.  I want to combine elements of underlying array with each other and then display it.  Finding a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to answering questions here - it's better than brain training though. I tried to infer some meaning from your problem, and decided it sounds like you have a list of teams and want to generate a list of fixtures. Here's a bit of code to do the job, although using String instead of int, but you should get the gist...

The result is all fixtures are stored in the "fixtures" list, and all are printed out by the statement on line 39.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FixtureGen 
{
    class Fixture
    {
        public Fixture(String teamA, String teamB)
        {
            this.teamA = teamA;
            this.teamB = teamB;
        }

        String teamA;
        String teamB;

        public String toString()
        {
            return teamA +" vs. "+teamB;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        FixtureGen gen = new FixtureGen();

        String[] teams = {"Spurs","Chelsea","Arsenal","Fulham","QPR","Palace"}; 
        List<String> teamList = Arrays.asList(teams);
        List<Fixture> fixtures = new ArrayList<Fixture>();

        for (String team : teamList)
        {
            fixtures.addAll(gen.getHomeFixtures(team, teamList));
        }

        for (Fixture fixture : fixtures)
        {
            System.out.println(fixture.toString());
        }
    }

    private  List<Fixture> getHomeFixtures(String team, List<String> teamList)
    {
        List<Fixture> fixtures = new ArrayList<Fixture>();
        Fixture fixture = null;
        for (String aTeam : teamList)
        {
            if (team != null && !team.equals(aTeam))
            {
                fixture = new FixtureGen.Fixture(team, aTeam);
                fixtures.add(fixture);
            }
        }
        return fixtures;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Java Map only supports *one* value per key.  So, when you put in [0,2], then later put in [0,7], the first key-value pair is replaced.  That's why you only see the 7s, the last value you put in.

There are third party implementations of MultiMaps, which support multiple values for each key.

Or, you could use a different data structure.  For example, if all the values will be integers, you could use a `Map<Integer, BitSet>` and add bits to the Bitset.  Be sure to test for a null Bitset the first time through.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just for printing, there is no need for a `Map`. You can just print the combinations in your loop.

If you do want to store them and cannot depend on third party libs to use a multi-map, consider writing your own container object (container for those 2 `int`s) and just put them in a `List` instead of a `Map`. Combine the container object with a decent `toString` implementation and printing will be easy as well